# How to Handle Multiple Resolution in Samsung Smart Tv

Tags: resolution, samsung-smart-tv

I want to handle multiple resolution in samsung smart tv app.We are using sdk 5.1. how can I get tv resolution ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle multiple resolution in Samsung smart TV app is to use % rather then fixed pixels e.g

```
body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

and keep in mind that smart TV dont come in small resolution, Widgets on Samsung Smart TV 2011+ support 960x540, 1280x720, widgets on 2012+ supports additionaly 1920x1080.

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to get screen dimensions.

However screen size is explicitly specified in `config.xml`. So it is unlikely, that your app will be displayed with different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

in Samsung TV (2011-2014) Orsay models you can add special file into root. This file is called
widged.info are there could be this two lines

Use Alpha Blending? = Yes
Screen Resolution = 1280x720

And now all your apps can be designed as 1280x720 resolution.

I hope that it helps you :)